# Unicode characters saved as � using JDBC, but saved correctly using phpMyAdmin

Tags: sql, jdbc, unicode, utf-8, utf8mb4

Here is how I create a connection:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("user", "root");
properties.setProperty("password", "PASSWORD");
properties.setProperty("useSSL", "false");
properties.setProperty("autoReconnect", "true");
properties.setProperty("useUnicode", "true");
properties.setProperty("characterEncoding", "UTF-8");
Connection connection =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/coolpoop", properties);

PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
statement.execute();
statement = connection.prepareStatement("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
statement.execute();
```

Table:

[image]

Inserting:

```
PreparedStatement state = Mysql.conn().prepareStatement("insert into contents(campaignId, site_id, original_article_id, title, content) values(-1, -1, -1, ?, ?)");
state.setString(1, "acbdąčęėįšųū");
state.setString(2, "acbdąčęėįšųū");
state.execute();
```

Result:

[image]

What is wrong?

EDIT1:
If I insert through phpMyAdmin, all good:
[image]

Comment: what's your database encoding? can you insert UTF-8 symbols via db client?

Comment: @BorysZibrov check EDIT1. Didn't check database encoding, but I suspect it should be fine, if I can insert through phpMyAdmin

Comment: yes, then db is fine, thanks

Comment: Is your .java source file saved with UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Gord, you're right! Thanks man.

Comment: So was this a case of file encoding defaulting to Cp1252 on Windows?

Comment: Does `SELECT LENGTH(title), CHAR_LENGTH(title) FROM ...` give you `20` and `12` for `'acbdąčęėįšųū`'?  If not, you have worse problems.  See [_Trouble_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for simply 'Black diamond', or (worse) 'double encoding'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases, Java development tools (e.g., Eclipse) use a default character encoding of `Cp1252` (a.k.a. `windows-1252`) for Java source files. That can cause strange encoding issues when working with Unicode characters because the source file encoding affects

1. how string literals are interpreted, and
2. the default character set used by the JVM when the project is run from within the IDE.

As in this case, a quick fix is to simply change the source file encoding to `UTF-8`.